# -$\infty$ cost in unconstrained LP problem?

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

I am trying to understand this lecture [slide (Finnish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTwNC.png) and the point in bold. It is a part of an OR condition, this is how I understand it. I cannot understand the optimal cost statement.

**Example**

> Suppose $$\min (-1)* x_1 \text{ so that } (1)*x_1\geq 2$$ so $$x_1\rightarrow \infty$$ but the point III mentions $-\infty$ cost, not $\infty$. Its dual $$\max (2)*p_1 \text{ so that } p_1\leq -1$$ so $$p_1\rightarrow-\infty.$$
>
> Is the cost the term $(-1)*x_1$ or is the *"optimal cost"* the term $x_1$? Usually, my teacher denotes the $(-1)*x_1$ as $c^t x$ where I have thought the term $c$ stands for cost but apparently wrong because here $c=-1$ and $x_1\rightarrow\infty\not = -\infty$.

**My translation of the slide**

> **"If the feasible set is non-empty and unbounded then**
>
> *1. Optimum exists and is in extreme point*
>
> *2. Optimum exists but not extreme point (cannot happen in standard form)*
>
> **3. Optimal cost is $-\infty$"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Value of objective function (what to be minimalized/maximalized) is called a cost, even in a dual problem.**

By the "cost" is usually referred value of $f(x)$, where $x$ denotes "when" the cost $f(x)$ "appears".

In your case $f(x)=c^Tx$, where $c=-1$. So the "cost" is $f(x)=-\infty$ and the argument (of that cost) is $x=\infty$

Comment: You mean that the cost is the thing to be optimized? Suppose a general form LP problem $\min c^T x \text{ so that } A x\geq b$. Is the term $c^T x$ equal to the cost?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: And the term $c$ is called the coeffient of the cost? Confusing to name it $c$ to mix with the cost term. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: One thing: what about the dual in the example? Is the optimized thing in it also called *"cost"*?

Comment: I can see your confusion, but $c$ is just a vector of coeficients for values of $x$. The $c^Tx$ is the cost (its a scalar). Maybe you could call the coeficients of $c$ as "costs" for entries of $x$, because it says, how much objective function (=cost) changes when you slightly change corresponding $x_i$ entry.

Comment: Value of objective function (what to be minimalized/maximalized) is called a cost, even in a dual problem.